# how to pass array to function in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Lack of my symfony knowledge bottlenecking me. i searched on web but not exactly solution found yet so here i am. How to pass `$parameters` to `sendmail function` rendering $data not working i think but it worked on to see but calling it ajax(**using ajax is not cause error but render**) is not working i guess.

```
**
* some route settings
**
function index(){
    ...
                $parameters = array(
                    'feedtitle' => $feedback->getTitle(),
                    'feedtype' => $feedback->getFeedtype(),
                    'feeddesc' => $feedback->getDescription(),
                    'feedpublish' => $feedback->getPublishedAt(),
                    'feedauthor' => $user->getFirstName() . ' ' . $user->getLastName(),
                );

                $this->sendEmail($parameters, $mailer, "info@fastap.com", 'proclaim@gmail.com');
}
function sendmail($data, $mailer, $from, $to){
    ...
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Хэрэглэгчдийн санал'))
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                // templates/emails/issue.html.twig
                    'email/issue.html.twig',
                    ['data' => $data]  <-- not working
                ),
                'text/html'
            )

            ...
}
```

here is issue.html.twig

```
<table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;font-family: sans-serif; text-align: left;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="font-size:14px;">
            <th style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">Name</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">Caption</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">Type</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">Description</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="font-size:12px;">
            <td style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">{{ data.feedauthor }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">{{ data.feedtitle }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">{{ data.feedtype }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">{{ data.feeddesc }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">{{ data.feedpublish }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<td style="border:1px solid #3d3d3d">{{ feedauthor }}</td>` etc

Comment: @u_mulder i edited my question i post tested one

Comment: Did you try to add a [`dump`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) of `data` ?

Comment: @GrenierJ yeah i dumped its working array do you wanna see ```array:5 [
  "feedtitle" => "1231231"
  "feedtype" => "request"
  "feeddesc" => "asdasdad"
  "feedpublish" => DateTime @1572947913 {#1476
    date: 2019-11-05 09:58:33.288874 UTC (+00:00)
  }
  "feedauthor" => "Bat Adminshuudee"
]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and i changed 
i changed my controller

```
             $parameters = array(
                    'feedtitle' => $feedback->getTitle(),
                    'feedtype' => $feedback->getFeedtype(),
                    'feeddesc' => $feedback->getDescription(),
                    'feedpublish' => $feedback->getPublishedAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), <-- forget to toString() date format
                    'feedauthor' => $user->getFirstName() . ' ' . $user->getLastName(),
                );
```

and its worked

Problem is its causing datetime to print out on twig i forget to convert and its working know

Answer (score 1):

You need to change parameter like this:

```
function sendmail($data, $mailer, $from, $to){
    ...
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Хэрэглэгчдийн санал'))
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                // templates/emails/issue.html.twig
                    'email/issue.html.twig',
                    ['data' => $data] 
                ),
                'text/html'
            )

            ...
}
```

Comment: Or not prefix your `twig variables` by `data`.

Comment: oh sorry i edited actually i posted wrong one i coding like this ```['data' => $data]``` i reedited that means its like your answer on my coding